# The name for a factor that determines the contribution of an individual within a team

Tags: game-theory

Some time ago I read an article on Wikipedia about a number/factor that describes the contribution factor of an individual within a group and I can't find the correct name for this number/figure anymore and I hope someone knows what I mean and can help out.

If I remember correctly, the general idea is that you consider for example 5 individual contributors A, B, C, D, E and let them solve tasks in teams of e.g. 3 with different permutations and measure the output of the team. For example team A,B,D achieves an output of 12. Team A,D,E accomplishes an output of 10 and so on. The goal is to assign every individual a "contribution factor" that basically measures how well the team performs. There is a special name/number for this that I forgot and it's not just solving linear equations.

Googling is hopeless, does someone here know what I mean?

Comment: To me, it sounds like the Shapley Value.

Comment: That's it!! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the Shapley Value.